# App not receiving MMS messages

Tags: android, mms

I am developing an SMS/MMS messaging system and I need the app to receive both SMS and MMS messages.  It receives SMS messages just fine.  I am testing on a real phone (Galaxy S7 Edge running 7.01).

The app does not receive MMS messages. According to [this post](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.html), my manifest is correct:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.webnation.text2email.receivers.MMSBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

However, setting a break point at the first line of the broadcast receiver, the broadcast receiver is never called. I am including all the right permissions.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

My broadcast receiver:

```
public class MMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  private static final String ACTION_MMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER";
  private static final String MMS_DATA_TYPE = "application/vnd.wap.mms-message";

  // Retrieve MMS
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context; <------- break point set here. 
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    int typeMessage = -1;
    byte[] pushData;
    GenericPdu pdu = null;
    Toast.makeText(context, "MMS received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (action.equals(ACTION_MMS_RECEIVED) && type.equals(MMS_DATA_TYPE)) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Timber.d("bundle " + bundle);
        if (bundle != null) {
            pushData = intent.getByteArrayExtra("data");
            PduParser parser = new PduParser(pushData);
            pdu = parser.parse();
            PduHeaders headers = pdu.getPduHeaders();

            Timber.d("buffer " + pushData);
            String incomingNumber = new String(pushData);
            int indx = incomingNumber.indexOf("/TYPE"); // not used, parse the number in MMUtils.getAddress instead
            if (indx > 0 && (indx - 15) > 0) {
                int newIndx = indx - 15;
                incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(newIndx, indx);
                char[] characters = incomingNumber.toCharArray();
                int index = 0;
                for (int i=0;i<characters.length;i++) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(characters[i]) ){


                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //indx = incomingNumber.indexOf("+");
                if (index > 0) {
                    incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(index);
                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(context.getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    String countryCode = tm.getNetworkCountryIso().toUpperCase();
                    try {
                        String prefix = CountryToPhonePrefix.prefixFor(countryCode).replace("+", "");
                        int indexOfBaseNumber = incomingNumber.indexOf(prefix);
                        if (indexOfBaseNumber > -1) {

                            if (indexOfBaseNumber == 0) {
                                int lengthPrefix = prefix.length();
                                indexOfBaseNumber = indexOfBaseNumber + lengthPrefix;
                            }
                            incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(indexOfBaseNumber);
                        }

                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
                        Timber.e(ie);
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ie) {
                        Timber.e(ie);;
                    }
                    Timber.d("Mobile Number: " + incomingNumber);
                }
            }

            int transactionId = bundle.getInt("transactionId", -1);
            Timber.d("transactionId " + transactionId);

            int pduType = bundle.getInt("pduType", -1);
            Timber.d("pduType " + pduType);

            byte[] buffer2 = bundle.getByteArray("header");

            if (buffer2 != null) {
                String header = new String(buffer2);
                Timber.d("header " + header);
            }
            List<MMSMessage> textMessages = MMSUtils.getMessagesFrom(context, intent); //meat of onReceive()
            sendMessages(textMessages);

        } else {
            Timber.e("Invalid PUSH data");
        }

    }


}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MikeM. I actually tried with WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED and it didn't work.

Comment: Well, what have you changed since this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039151/trying-to-receive-an-mms-message-android#comment85110035_49039151?

Comment: @MikeM. Absolutely nothing except the WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED.

Comment: I guess I'm not following, here. Are you saying it never worked? Or it doesn't work on this particular device? Or it stopped working when you upgraded versions? Or something else?

Comment: It doesn't work on my device - not sure if it would run on other devices.  It worked briefly after adding a correct permission in debug, then did not work when not in debug at all.  Then I tried adding WAP_PUSH_DELIVER and it is still not working.

Comment: Also, are you certain the received messages are actually MMS? Might they possibly be [RCS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38046131)? If so, your Receiver won't fire for those at all.

Comment: Yes, positive they are MMS messages.  My messaging app labels them as MMS messages.

Comment: OK, though I wouldn't necessarily trust that blindly. :-) Anyhoo, I've got an S7 on 7.0, so I'll run a few tests later myself, when I get a chance, and let ya know if I find anything useful.

Comment: Yeah, and just FYI, I've offered a bounty on my previous question.  Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Well, I (eventually) had no problem receiving MMS, even when not the default, in both debug and release builds. At first, I had Advanced Messaging (another term for RCS; there are several different names for it) enabled, and I was puzzled for a bit, until I remembered to disable it. After that, it works as expected. Who's your cellular provider? Can you receive when you're the default, with `WAP_PUSH_DELIVER`? Are you _really_ sure those messages are MMS? You might try doing a `ContentResolver#query()` just to make sure.

Comment: Other than that, the only thing I can think of at the moment is to check if your device has additional security stuff that might prevent third-party apps from receiving MMS, though I'd imagine that would block SMS, as well.

Comment: @MikeM. My provider is Sprint.  I also tried sending myself MMS messages using my default gateway by sending via email <mynumber>@pm.sprint.com.  So pretty sure my messaging is MMS.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to my main activity in the Manifest seems to have solved the problem:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.webnation.text2email.main.SMSEmailActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```